# JS base n string to base64

Tags: javascript, string, radix

I have a string (with numbers under 128) separated by a comma:

```
"127,25,34,52,46,2,34,4,6,1"
```

Because there are 10 digits and one comma, that makes 11 total characters. How can I convert this string from "base 11" to "base 64"? I would like to compress this string into base64. I tried window.btoa, but it produces a larger output because the browser doesn't know that the string only has 11 characters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `10 digits and one comma` but I count 10 numbers comprised of 17 digits and 9 commas for 26 total characters. `"How can I convert this string from "base 11"` this string is not in base11. `I would like to compress this string into base64` base64 always creates a larger string, it doesn't compress it. `but it produces a larger output because the browser doesn't know that the string only has 11 characters` It does not have only 11 characters, it has 26, and regardless, again base64 always creates a larger string

Comment: base64 has a strict definition, and is not a tool to compress. You want compression... and that is not called base64.

Comment: The character set has 11 characters, like how base64 has 64 characters. I know that for ASCII, base64 is not "compression" because 128>64. But for 11 characters, it is "compression".

Comment: Does converting hex to base64 make it shorter? Yes, because 16<64.

Comment: I think  that 127 - is seven bit and you can accumulate 1byte from eight numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 encoding never produces shorter strings. It is not intended as a compression tool, but as a means to reduce the used character set to 64 readable characters, taking into account that the input may use a larger characterset (even if not all those characters are used).

Given the format of your string, why not take those numbers and use them as ASCII, and then apply Base64 encoding on that?

Demo:

```js
let s = "127,25,34,52,46,2,34,4,6,1";
console.log(s);

let encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode(...s.match(/\d+/g)));
console.log(encoded);

let decoded = Array.from(atob(encoded), c => c.charCodeAt()).join();
console.log(decoded);
```